# "Snapped geometry has invalid geometry" error when snapping geometries to layer

Tags: qgis-3, layers, geometry, qgis-processing, snapping

I have two shape layers in QGIS where I want to use the "Snap Geometries to Layer". I get the error message that several polygons of the Reference layer have invalid geometries:

> Feature (1) from “Snapped geometry” has invalid geometry and has been
> skipped. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to
> the “Ignore invalid input features” option.

How do I find the feature in the attribute table? Which column does QGIS mean? I'd like to fix the geometries before using the algorithm again.

Comment: Searching "qgis invalid geometry" bring lots of answer, review a few of those and see if that help you fix your problem

Comment: There is "fix geometries" processing toolbox in qgis

Comment: I wonder how I can find the feature in the attribute table. What does QGIS mean by "Feature (1)"?

Comment: "Feature (1)" means that 1 feature is invalid. Use "check validity" to create another layer which is invalid.

Comment: In addition to Aman's suggestions you could use the Topology Checker to find invalid geometries and other errors if you like.  Clicking on each one in the window zooms you to the error.